# Do I need a transit visa for my travel from Antalya to London that I have a transfer at Denmark Aalborg for 2 hours?

Tags: visas, schengen, customs-and-immigration, transit-visas, aal

Do I need a transit visa for my travel from Antalya to London that I have a transfer at Denmark Aalborg for 2 hours?

I am a Turkish citizen, I am living in UK and currently I am holding a EEA family permit. I am travelling with my son and he is citizen of Latvia. I tried to book my flights and I have seen a notice that I may need a transit visa for Denmark. I am confused and I need a correct information about this subject.

Comment: @gdrt: The relevant uncertainty here is whether Aalborg Airport allows international transit without entering the Schengen area (it has barely any connecting passengeres at all, Schengen or not), which the older question doesn't answer.

Comment: Missed that part, then I'm voting up your answer.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Not uncertain in the slightest, see my answer

Comment: Is your "Family Permit" a sticker in your passport or is it a card?

Answer (score 3):

Aalborg airport is quite small and **does not have a non-Schengen transit area**, so you will need to enter the Schengen area for your transit. (It is not easy to find this information on the net, but I emailed the airport and asked, and they responded unequivocally that you will pass immigration checks both on arrival and when departing).

Your son will have no problems if he travels on a Latvian passport; as an EU citizen he has freedom of movement in the entire union.

You **most probably need a visa**, unless in addition to (or instead of) the EEA Family Permit you *also* have a `residence card of a family member of a Union citizen` (and even so, there is some doubt left; see the comments).

You need an *ordinary short-stay Schengen visa* -- an airport transit visa is *not* enough.

Comment: The parent of an EU citizen does not derive freedom of movement rights from the child unless the parent is dependent on the child.  If the child is a minor and the father has an article 10 card based on the marriage to the mother, I think the father cannot rely on freedom of movement when traveling alone with the son.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I can tell you in advance - he Needs a visa. Only through Kastrup does he not

Comment: @phoog: I think there might be an argument that if the OP is traveling to **join**, say, a spouse in the UK, then an Article 10 card ought to be valid for transiting through a different Member State (in this case, Denmark).

Comment: @HenningMakholm yes, indeed, that must be true.

Answer (score 1):

Citizens of Turkey do not require an airport transit visa in Denmark.

Residents of EU countries do not require an airport transit visa in Denmark.

You do not require an airport transit visa in Denmark.

Source: http://canada.um.dk/en/travel-and-residence/visas/airport-transit-visa

However, I am unfamiliar with the airport, so do pay heed to Henning Makholm's answer.  If there is no international transit zone, you'll need to be able to enter the Schengen area, which an airport transit visa does not permit.  If you do need a visa, it will have to be a Schengen short stay visa.

Comment: AAL doesn't have sterile transit

Answer (score 0):

The only Danish airport with an international transfer corridor is Copenhagen, as stated in [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=TR&AR=GB&PASSTYPES=PASS&selDest=Use+ctrl-key+to+select+or+deselect+destination%28s%29+above&TR=DK&selTrans=Denmark&user=OLYMPIC&subuser=OLYMPICB2C), the database used by airlines:

> Visa required, except for Holders of onward tickets transiting on the same calendar day **if arriving at and departing from Copenhagen Kastrup (CPH)**

Is the "Family permit" a visa in your passport, or a card? If it's a card, you can enter Denmark to catch the connecting flight to the UK together with your son.

> Visa required, **except** for Passengers with a family member residence card issued by United Kingdom. The card must be issued to family members of a national of Switzerland or an EEA Member State. They are visa exempt for a maximum stay of 90 days and must **travel with** or travel to join **the national of** Switzerland or **EEA Member State**.

As the father of a Latvian citizen, [you qualify as a family member under this regulation](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=celex:32004L0038):

> For the purposes of this Directive: [...] "Family member" means [...]
>   (d) the dependent direct relatives **in the ascending line** and those of the spouse or partner as defined in point (b);

So if you have a family member **card** and are travelling with your son, you do **not** Need a visa.

If you have an actual EEA Family permit (a visa in the passport), however, you **do** need a visa, and **not** an airport transit visa, but a full (C-type) Schengen visa (selecting transit as the purpose in the application form).

As you probably know, your son only needs a Latvian passport or ID card.

Comment: ...unless the so-called EEA family permit is actually an article 10 card, which seems likely since the question states he is "living in the UK," and the card was either issued because of the son or because of another EU-citizen relative who is already in the UK.

Comment: As the father of an EEA citizen, he only qualifies for freedom of movement on the basis of that relationship if he is *dependent on the son.*  The source you've quoted notes that, but your own text does not.  If the son is by contrast dependent on the father (or on someone else, or is independent) then the father's freedom of movement rights must derive from someone else.

Comment: @phoog If he indeed has this card, he obviously qualified, as he wouldn't have got it otherwise. If it's on the basis of someone else in the UK, he can enter Denmark on the basis of travelling to the UK to join that someone, while if he got on the basis of his son, it's obviously Ok to fly with him.

Comment: What if the someone isn't in the UK?  Perhaps she or he is in Antalya.

Comment: @phoog Then, unless OP got the Card on the Basis of his son, a visa will be required. We don't know if he actually has a Card though. If not, he absolutely Needs a Schengen visa